# How to create a custom search component using lightning

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have been struggling trying to create a custom component for searching through objects using lightning. I have been on trailhead and the only reference to such is the [Lightning Communities: Create a custom search component](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/communities_theme_layout/steps/custom_search). I have made attempts to replicate this code, however It doesn't seem to work as I expect it it. I believe it has to do with the way the code is setup for communities.

Does anyone have any sample code I can use for instance to search for e.g. Account Name or Account Number that then displays a list of Accounts or any other object (doesnt necessarily have to be accounts but something that highlights the logic) which I can drag and drop then onto a page?

Answer (score 1):

The  Lightning Communities: Create a custom search component trailhead you linked provides most of what you need, however, it is sending the query directly to the server, so, if you intend on implementing something where the query needs to be updated, your end users will have to wait an eternity to get results (not a good idea).

Unfortunately there is no magic formula to achieving what you want, however, here are some tips:

> - Depending on the amount of data that needs to be queried, you might want to send 1 query to the server(or multiple) to fetch and store
>     client side.
> - Depending on your needs, use SOSL or SOQL.
> - Based on [How TO - Filter/Search List](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp) you
>     will want to filter/query your data from a component controller, the
>     code in the link should provide more than enough for you to get
>     something going.

Comment: The thing is I do not want to use communities, how do I adopt the code in such a way that it can be a drag and drop component I can add to a page while retaining its functionality.

Comment: use an interface that is not for communities, it ill work for pretty much anywhere, here is a list of available interfaces, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/interfaces and if you need it in visualforce, simply embed the component in a visualforce page